# Moving files based on CSV values from two columns

Tags: file, powershell, csv, directory, move

I have been working on a script which moves files in a directory to a child directory which is created if the column 'folder' contains a 'Y'. The files which have no 'Y' in thier respective folder column are moved in to the folder of the most previous file name with a Y.

I seem to be having some issue with the move-item cmdlet. This has been affecting me with the rename-item in another script im attempting so i think it has something to do with how im attempting to access the file name of existing files in a folder.

```
$sourceDir = read-host "Please enter source Dir:"

$csv = import-csv C:\scripts\files\files.csv
$csv | where {$_.folder -eq 'Y'} | % {

        $path = $sourceDir + "\" + $_.fileName
        if(-not $_.PSIsContainer)
        {
            md $path
        }#end if
    }#end for

$move = ".\" + $csv[0].fileName 
$csv | % {
            if ($_.folder -eq 'Y')
            {
                $move = ".\" + $_.fileName
                mi $_.fileName "$move"
            }
            mi $_.fileName "$move"
        } #end for
```

Again the mi seems to be throwing the error. The first for loop creates the folders correctly but the second falls down. I was fiddling with it and I was able to make it move the files which correspond.

Sorry that was an older version of the script after I was having problems with the moving.

```
Move-Item : Cannot find path 'C:\scripts\BB.026.001.001.0017' because it does not exist.
At C:\scripts\Y2.ps1:25 char:7
+                 mi  <<<< $_.fileName "$move"
Move-Item : Cannot find path 'C:\scripts\BB.026.001.001.0017' because it does not exist.
At C:\scripts\Y2.ps1:27 char:6
+             mi  <<<< $_.fileName "$move"
Move-Item : Cannot find path 'C:\scripts\BB.026.001.001.0018' because it does not exist.
At C:\scripts\Y2.ps1:27 char:6
+             mi  <<<< $_.fileName "$move
```

"

The extension of the file as well as the correct path need to be referenced
Thanks,

Craig.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I'm unsure as to where you have the file extension stored, but I've rewritten your script putting everything into one foreach loop with an IF statement to enumerate whether a folder should be created.

```
$sourceDir = "C:\Temp\sotemp\Source\"                                #Configure source file directory
$destDir = "C:\Temp\sotemp\Dest\"                                    #Configure destination file directory
$csv = import-csv 'C:\Temp\sotemp\files.csv'                         #Import CSV file

$csv | % {                                                           #For each line in the CSV
            $sourceFile = $sourceDir + $_.fileName + ".txt"
            if($_.folder -eq 'Y'){                                   #If the csv entry has a Y in the folder column
                $destPath = $destDir + $_.fileName                   #Build the destination directory path
                if (!(Test-Path -path $destPath)){                   #If the destination directory doesn't exist...
                    New-Item $destPath -itemtype directory -force    #Force creation of the destination directory if it doesn't exist
                }
                mi $sourceFile $destPath                             #Move the file!
            }
            else {
                $destPath = $destPath                                #This isn't needed, but it explicitly shows we are reusing the $destPath variable with whatever was in it the last time we populated it
                mi $sourceFile $destPath                             #Move the file!
            }
        }
```

Let me know if I'm way off target here, if I'm on target, you would just need to update the paths and file extension.  In addition, there is no error checking and I haven't used the '-force' parameter on file move to force an overwrite.  The script is also reliant on the first row in the CSV having a 'Y' in the folder column to ensure the $destPath variable is populated.

Comment: Sorry that was an older version after i deleted the one i was working (failing) on please look at the updated error

Comment: Can I ask what is in the fileName column of the CSV? Is it a list of fileNames like BB.026.001.001.0017 or is it something like BB.026.001.001.0017.txt (i.e. with an extension).  I need to understand where the file extension is recorded.  If all the files have the same extension then we could just hard code it.

Comment: the CSV is a file with headings fileName and folder and within there are a list of DocIds there is no extension. I feel one of the issues i have been encountering was with the fact the move-item cmdlet cant locate the file as i was not specifying an extension. am i correct in saying to get the file correctly it would be $newName = $_.fileName + ".txt" to appent .txt and then use it as the full file name, i am not sure how else to do this in case there is a built in function

Comment: Move-Item will need the full filename, including the extension so yes, $newName = $_.fileName + ".txt" should form a valid filename.

Comment: Files do have an 'extension' property but as we're getting the fileNames from the CSV without the extension, we have to add it as above.